# How to use SqlCeParameterCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I wanna to know exactly how we do these thing on C# .NET 4.0 Form Application:

- Declaring SqlCeParameterCollection Object
- Adding Parameters to the collection
- Add the Collection to the Command

Here are samples of my current code:

- Declaring & Adding

  ```
  SqlCeParameterCollection Parameters = new SqlCeCommand().Parameters;
  Parameters.Add("username", Username);
  Parameters.Add("password", Password);
  ```

Now how to add this collection at once to the command?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
string query = "...(whatever you need).....";

using(SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn))
{ 
    // just add parameters directly to SqlCeCommand object .... 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("username", Username);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("password", Password);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // or whatever you need to do 
    conn.Close();
}
```

If you **must** set up your parameters separately, up front, then you need to do something like this (since you cannot directly use `SqlCeParameterCollection`):

```
List<SqlCeParameters> parameters = new List<SqlCeParameters>();

parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter(.....));
parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter(.....));

string query = "...(whatever you need).....";

using(SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn))
{ 
    // add all parameters from the list - casting to an array
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // or whatever you need to do 
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection.AddRange(System.Array)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Another Error : The type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeParameterCollection' has no constructors defined

Comment: I need to do it that way because of coding standards that we are following in the entity.

Comment: @Hatem: the `SqlCeParameterCollection` is not a type intended to be instantiated and used separately. It's intended to be used only in the context of the `SqlCeCommand.Parameters` property...

Comment: @Hatem: updated my answer with another approach - could that work for you?

Comment: I put it new SqlCeCommand().Parameters;
but what about the first error ? it seems that was not the correct use of AddRange !

Comment: @Hatem: I **UPDATED** my response with a new approach - which **should** work with the `.AddRange()` method!

Answer (score 1):

`SqlCeCommand.Parameters` is [read only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so you won't be able to assign a new `SqlParametersCollection` directly to this property.

You typically want to use the [CreateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.createcommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) factory method on `SqlCeConnection` to create the command (as it will link the connection for you).

Then you use the `command.Parameters` directly:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
// cmd.CommandType = ...; cmd.CommandText = ...
cmd.Parameters.Add("username", Username);
cmd.Parameters.Add("password", Password);
```

Comment: So , there are no way to add the collection at once ? Am passing the collection to a function and that function will build the command ? so any suggestion ?

Comment: @Hatem - marc_s answer shows a way of copying all Parameters from an IList across to the `SqlCeCommand.Parameters` using AddRange()