# Suggestions on C# SQL parameters (collection) passed to function?

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

I would like to build a SQL function that has large amounts of reuse with `ExecuteNonQuery` but the biggest issue I have are the parameters.

I am not sure what others would do to make this simple and resilient so that I can simply pass the SQL script.

For example `SELECT * FROM table WHERE userid = @userid AND isactive = @isactive`, and then perhaps the peramiters can be an array.

```
public void ExecuteSQLCeNonQuery(string _Sql, ?parameter array of some type?)
{
    SqlCeConnection sCon = null;
    SqlCeCommand sCmd = null;
    int countOf = 0;

    try
    {
        sCon = new SqlCeConnection( sqlConnectionStringLocal);
        sCmd = new SqlCeCommand(_Sql, sCon);

        sCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recBatchDateTarget", sDateOnly); <----- I know this will have to parse the collection some how.

        sCon.Open();
        countOf = (int)sCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sCon.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlCeException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("** DEBUG: ExecuteSQLCeNonQuery: {0} - {1}", ex.Message, sSql);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (sCmd != null)
            sCmd.Dispose();

        if (sCon != null)
            sCon.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to handle the array or collection of parameters?

Comment: [Are you talking about this ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425668/sql-parameter-collection)

Comment: Reinventing the wheel? Don't we already have enough ORMs? It's 2013 guys...

Comment: You could do a variable argument thing: public void ExecuteSQLCeNonQuery(string _Sql, params object[] args ); Then the caller would call ExecuteSQLCeNonQuery( "--query text", "length", 37, "height", 6.5 ); In ExecuteSQLCeNonQuery, you'd walk through args two indexes at a time. For each pair of elements, throw an exception unless args[i] is a string, and args[i+1] is < args.Length. If that's all OK, "@"+args[i] is the param name, and args[i+1] is it's value. Put a /// comment on it so intellisense works. You'll have to check runtime types on the values and get the types right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare it as an `IEnumerable<SqlParameter>` so the caller can provide any collection he wants (array, `List<SqlParameter>`, ...)

```
public void ExecuteSQLCeNonQuery(string _Sql, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
    ...
    if (parameters != null) // Null check so caller can pass null if there are no parameters
    {
        foreach(SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Prix and Joe, I would vote you up but don't have the rep yet.  Let me work those in.

Answer (score 1):

Following the rabbit hole let me to this post.  The .AddRange method for the parameters should work.

[How to use SqlCeParameterCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062162/how-to-use-sqlceparametercollection/13062381#13062381)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make a separate class for accessing data,
and place your methods there(like delete method,update,insert,etc..),
your connectionstring,if always accessing same database,could be outside the methods.
In your methods parameters you can pass a string with your formatted
sql statements,setting your sqlcommand object to that parameter.
You can make that class static or public(you would then need to
instatiate it in your clientform).

ex:
inside clientform....

```
string query = "SELECT * from tablename";
sqlaccessclass sqlclass = new sqlaccessclass();
sqlclass.GetAll(query);
```

Your return type for fetching data methods would be DataSet while in ExecuteNonQuery
methods would be void.